# Gurobi taking a long time to build model for LP

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi

I have been solving some LPs with gurobi, and I noticed that for most of the instances I am encountering, building the model is taking way longer than actually solving it. Perhaps this is standard, but it seems bizarre to me.

One particular instance took 1.75 seconds to solve, but the following portion of the code for building the model took 13.6 seconds:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numSeq2; ++i) {
    expr = new GRBLinExpr();
    //expr.clear();
    for (int j = 0; j < numSeq1; ++j)
        expr.addTerm(-1 * A[j][i], x[j]);
    for (int j = 0; j < numIS2; ++j)
        expr.addTerm(-1 * F[j][i], q[j]);
    duals[i] = model.addConstr(expr, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, 0, "");
}
```

In the example described above, numSeq1 = 7475, numSeq2 = 7475, numIS2 = 2517, and the final LP had 9992 rows and 9992 columns. I know this is fairly large, but it seems strange that it takes almost 10x as much time to build the model than to solve it.

I tried expr.clear() instead of creating a new GRBLinExpr for each constraint (commented out) and it didn't help.

Is there any way to make gurobi build the model any faster? Would cplex be better than gurobi in this regard if the bottleneck is building the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, there was a big typo in the blocks of your sample code (now corrected). This makes me wonder if your model is supposed to have `numSeq2` rows (7495).

If every element in your A and F matrices is non-zero, then the structure of your code is fine.  However, this is extremely uncommon; in most cases, the vast majority of matrix coefficients are zero.  If so, you should call GRBLinExpr.addTerm() for only the non-zero elements in the rows.  This is true regardless of whether you are using Gurobi or any other solver.

(Note that you may get a faster response for Gurobi-specific questions on Gurobi's own discussion forum.)

Disclaimer: I currently work for Gurobi Optimization and formerly worked for ILOG, which provided CPLEX.

Comment: Hi Gregg, what is the typo? There was a problem with the indentation in the sample code when I copy/pasted it, which I just fixed. Also, numSeq2 should be 7475 in the example (same as numSeq1), which I just fixed (that part was a typo). The model is supposed to have numSeq2 rows, that is correct. As I commented below, using addTerms() instead of addTerm() helped a little. I will also try your suggestion with the zero coefficients, and check out Gurobi's forum. Thanks!

Comment: Ignoring the zero coefficients solved the problem, thanks! It's now taking 1-2 seconds per LP instead of 12-15!

Comment: Usually you can speed up the model building even more if you avoid addTerm and use addTerms instead. http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.0/refman/cs_grblinexpr.html

Answer (score -2):

Since you are asking about alternatives, I believe you would be better off using an algebraic modeling language such as AMPL, AIMMS or open source alternatives such as GLPK and AML. These declarative languages allow to concisely and elegantly formulate your problem. These languages generate MPS or NL that can then be processed by CPLEX or alternative free solvers. As you can see, the modeling language is one thing, the solver is another.

Comment: Tarik: Supposing I only care about speed right now (and not elegance or conciseness), do you think those other languages would help?

Comment: No: properly written code with an interpreted modeling language will not be faster than properly written code using a solver API. The short reason for this is that the modeling systems themselves call the solver APIs.

Comment: I honestly do not know.  Unless someone happens to be experienced with Gurobi, I do not think you should expect much of an answer on this site. That said, although large, your problem seems quite simple and it would not cost much in terms of time to investigate alternatives such as generating MPS input files which happen to be in text form and would not require much of a learning curve.

Comment: Ok thanks Gregg and Tarik. Btw, I was able to shave a few seconds off by putting the coefficients into matrices and using the addTerms(double[], GRBVar[]) function instead of addTerm(double, GRBVar). I guess that is probably the best speed improvement I could hope for.

Comment: @Greg Glockner Since you happen to be the Gurobi guru, you might help beserious solve his original performance problem. That said, AFAIK, algebraic modeling languages are not interpreted. They are either compiled into NL or MPS or any input supported by solvers or directly call the solver API to build the problem before launching the solver itself. Example: AIMMS supports using Gurobi as a solver.

Comment: @Tarik Modeling languages like AMPL or GAMS interpret the model file at runtime. This is the definition of an interpreted language.

Comment: @Greg Glockner As per Wikipedia "The interpreter executes the program source code directly, statement by statement, as a processor or scripting engine does. This can be contrasted with compiled language programs, which the user must explicitly translate into a lower-level machine language executable". In the case of AMPL and other algebraic modeling languages, the model and data are transformed into matrix form that is then crunched by the solver. I do not see any relevance to interpretation as defined above, unless you have a peculiar definition of your own.